# Pascal's triangle in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pascals-triangle

I'm trying to write a code which receives an integer "n" as a parameter and then print the n-th row of the Pascal's triangle starting from 0, 1,..,n.
for example if the entry is 3, the program prints 1 3 3 1.
So far I wrote a code to get the whole triangle printed, but I can't have just the last row.
This is what I have

```
echo "Insert the row:" read n for((i=0;i<$n;i++)) 
do      
eval"a$i=($(w=1;v=1
        for((j=0;j<$n-$i;j++))
        do 
            [ $i -eq 0 -o $j -eq 0 ]&&{ v=1 && w=1; }||v=$((w+a$((i-1))[$((j))]))
            echo -n "$v "
            w=$v
        done))"
     eval echo "$(for((k=0;k<=$i;k++)) 
        do 
            eval "echo -n \"\$((a\$((i-k))[k])) \"" 
        done)" 
    done
```

Comment: If you just want the last row why don't you use the formula for binomial expansion?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no, the code doesn't work as intended, so it's NOT good for Code Review SE

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Insert the row:"  n

typeset -A Tab

for((i=0;i<=$n;i++))
do
  Tab[$i,0]=1
  Tab[$i,$i]=1
  for((j=1;j<$i;j++))
  do
    a=${Tab[$((i-1)),$((j-1))]}
    b=${Tab[$((i-1)),$j]}
    Tab[$i,$j]=$(( a + b ))
  done
done

#print result
for((j=0;j<=$n;j++))
do
  echo -n ${Tab[$n,$j]} " "
done
echo
```

Test :

```
Insert the row:3
1  3  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an `awk` solution to that question:

```
awk -v line_num=5 'BEGIN{for(i=line_num;i<=line_num;i++){c=1;r=c;for(j=0;j<i;j++){c*=(i-j)/(j+1);r=r" "c};print r}}'
```

Change `line_num` value to the desired one.

Based on a solution found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#AWK).

That's of course if `awk` counts…

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple bash script to print pascal's triangle using simple for,if else and echo command:

```
echo "Enter number of rows : "
read rows
coef=1
for((i=0;i<rows;i++))
do
  for((space=1;space<=rows-i; space++))
  do
    echo -n "  "
  done
  for((j=0;j<=i;j++))
  do
    if [ $j -eq 0 -o $i -eq 0 ]
    then
        coef=1;
    else
        coef=$((coef*(i-j+1)/j))
    fi
    echo -n $coef "   "
  done
  echo
done
```